# AttributeError: module 'mediapipe.python.solutions.holistic' has no attribute 'FACE_CONNECTIONS'

Tags: python, face-detection, mediapipe

need help this is my code:

```py
import mediapipe as mp 

mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils # Drawing helpers
mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic # Mediapipe Solutions

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Initiate holistic model
with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:
    
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        
        # Recolor Feed
        image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image.flags.writeable = False        
        
        # Make Detections
        results = holistic.process(image)
        # print(results.face_landmarks)
        
        # face_landmarks, pose_landmarks, left_hand_landmarks, right_hand_landmarks
        
        # Recolor image back to BGR for rendering
        image.flags.writeable = True   
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        
        # 1. Draw face landmarks
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.face_landmarks, mp_holistic.FACE_CONNECTIONS, 
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,110,10), thickness=1, circle_radius=1),
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,256,121), thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
                                 )
        
        # 2. Right hand
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.right_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS, 
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,22,10), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,44,121), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                                 )

        # 3. Left Hand
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.left_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS, 
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(121,22,76), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(121,44,250), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                                 )

        # 4. Pose Detections
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_holistic.POSE_CONNECTIONS, 
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,117,66), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,66,230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                                 )
                        
        cv2.imshow('Raw Webcam Feed', image)

        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: please pay attention to the formatting of your post. code can be styled to look like code with very little effort.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Please read [ask]. (The single line error message in your title is not sufficient. Errors should be presented with full tracebacks.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just looked into the sourcecode at https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/python/solutions/holistic.py

`FACE_CONNECTIONS` seems to be renamed/replaced by `FACEMESH_TESSELATION`.

Just changing that name in the code should work.

PS: If you want just the outlines of the face, it's now `FACEMESH_CONTOURS`

Answer (score 1):

install 0.8.5 version its worked for me